# How to find the Laurent series $\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}$ at point $z_0 = i$?

Tags: complex-analysis

How to find the Laurent series $\frac{1}{1+z^{2}}$ in point $z_0 = i$?

My sketch

$$1/(1+z^{2}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}z^{2n}$$

I tried:

$$w = z - i$$
$$z = w + i$$
So the Laurent series about $-i$ is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(w+i)^{2n}$$

This is correct?

Comment: Hint: What is the partial fraction decomposition of $1/(1+z^2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{z^{2}+1}&=\dfrac{1}{z-i}\dfrac{1}{z+i}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{z-i}\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{z-i}{2i}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2i}\dfrac{1}{z-i}\left(1-\dfrac{z-i}{2i}+\left(\dfrac{z-i}{2i}\right)^{2}-\cdots\right)
\end{align*}